# Javascript Regex expression not working with string having the format "(content)"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am trying to use the regex function of JavaScript to replace my string with desired value.But the regex keeps failing when the string has this format  **'(content)'**

Here's my code for Regex:

```js
     changeFormat = function (oldValue, newValue) {
      var changeData = "http://www.semanticweb.ontology-91#rabindranath_tagore_(film)";
      var regex = new RegExp(oldValue, 'g');
      console.log(regex);
      var source = changeData.replace(regex, newValue);
      console.log(source);
    };
    
    
changeFormat("http://www.semanticweb.ontology-91#rabindranath_tagore_(film)","rabindranath_tagore_(film)");
```

I got my output as "**http://www.semanticweb.ontology-91#rabindranath_tagore_(film)**" instead of "**rabindranath_tagore_(film)**"

The above behavior is because of the brackets "()".

Comment: escape the brackets with `\(` and `\)`

Comment: @Tushortz.Where exactly do i add that?in the string?

Comment: Yes - brackets have a special meaning in regex, so `"rabindranath_tagore_(film)"` would actually match `rabindranath_tagore_film`. For the record, dots also have a special meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to escape your string properly. As you see in the comments above as well, brackets and dots `( and ) and .` contain a special meaning when it comes to regex.

Here, this should do: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711))

```
function escape(s) {
  return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
function escape(s) {
  return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

changeFormat = function(oldValue, newValue) {
  var changeData = "http://www.semanticweb.ontology-91#rabindranath_tagore_(film)";
  var regex = new RegExp(escape(oldValue), 'g');
  console.log(regex);
  var source = changeData.replace(regex, newValue);
  console.log(source);
};


changeFormat("http://www.semanticweb.ontology-91#rabindranath_tagore_(film)", "rabindranath_tagore_(film)");
```

Comment: For the record `[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]` is completely correct. A lot of characters lose their special meaning inside square brackets and don't need to be escaped. Lots of times I see a regex with `[\.]` which can be quite difficult to read in a longer group. However, it's worth mentioning that `-` is valid to not be escaped as it is now - in the beginning of the character class. It's also valid if it's in the end. If there are any characters before AND after, then it should technically be escaped, although a `[.-+]` will still probably match only the three characters, a `[.\-+]` is better.